# Reset Html:multibox to original values after hitting cancel button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a html:multibox having checked values when loading the page set in action class. if i check other checkbox and hit cancel. its should restore the original values.
here is my code

```
<div class="regmultibox">
    <html:multibox styleId="regWE`" property="regions" value="WE"></html:multibox>
    <label for="regWE">chkbox1</label><br />
    <html:multibox styleId="regWC" property="regions" value="WC"></html:multibox>
    <label for="regWC">chkbox2</label>
 </div>
<div class="regmultibox">
    <html:multibox styleId="regMW" property="regions" value="MW"></html:multibox>
    <label for="regMW">chkbox3</label><br /> 
    <html:multibox styleId="regSW" property="regions" value="SW">
    </html:multibox>
    <label for="regSW">chkbox4</label><br />
</div>
<div class="regmultibox">
    <html:multibox styleId="regNE" property="regions" value="NE"></html:multibox>
    <label for="regNE">chkbox5</label><br />
    <html:multibox styleId="regSE" property="regions" value="SE">
    </html:multibox>
     <label for="regSE">chkbox6</label>
</div>
<div class="regmultibox">
    <html:multibox styleId="regMA" property="regions" value="MA">
    </html:multibox>
    <label for="regMA">chkbox7</label><br />

</div>
<li>
<div id="buttonSubmitCancel">
    <label></label>
    <div id="form_foot_panel">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" value="Submit">
        <html:cancel styleClass="submit"/>
    </div>
    <div></div>
</div>
</li>
```

Comment: save the initial values in the localStorage before updating them and restore on cancel

Comment: I think that you need to clarify more that you want, I can figure out, but is necessary more information, your tags say that your question is about js and jquery, but you only put html, so in summary  you need to edit  you question in order to get the answer that you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like this:
(**Not tested**)

```
<c:forEach items="${original_values}" var="item" > 
   <html-el:multibox property="your_name" value="${item.key}"/> 
   <c:out value="${item.key}"/> - 
   <c:out value="${item.value.yourvalue}"/> 
</c:forEach>
```